# green house vent servo based reading a sensor wrong

Tags: servo

I am trying to make a green house vent that will open based on the temperature, however in my code the thermometer is not reading correctly, I've been designing it  in tinkercad and heres the link
https://www.tinkercad.com/things/fxhHvZCoqmQ
when the thermometer is on A0 i9t reads 14, if its on A3 it is 17.
I am very new at this so please help.

Comment: post your code in the question directly.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: What is the problem with the code, because I can't see any problems.